# Is there a way to combine named scopes into a new named scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, named-scope

I have

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :a, lambda { |a| :conditions => { :a => a } }
  named_scope :b, lambda { |b| :conditions => { :b => b } }
end
```

I'd like

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :ab, lambda { |a,b| :conditions => { :a => a, :b => b } }
end
```

but I'd prefer to do it in a DRY fashion.  I can get the same effect by using

```
 Foo.a(something).b(something_else)
```

but it's not particularly lovely.

Comment: it seems that this behaviour is no default in rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'm still new to rails and I'm not sure exactly what you're going for here, but if you're just going for code reuse why not use a regular class method?

```
        def self.ab(a, b)
            a(a).b(b)
        end
```

You could make that more flexible by taking *args instead of a and b, and then possibly make one or the other optional.  If you're stuck on named_scope, can't you extend it to do much the same thing?

Let me know if I'm totally off base with what you're wanting to do.

Comment: With this solution it won't behave the scope as a normal scope does. For e.g. it won't be in `Model.scopes`.

Answer (score 15):

At least since 3.2 there is a clever solution :

```
scope :optional, ->() {where(option: true)}
scope :accepted, ->() {where(accepted: true)}
scope :optional_and_accepted, ->() { self.optional.merge(self.accepted) }
```

Answer (score 1):

By making it a class method you won't be able to chain it to an association proxy, like:

```
@category.products.ab(x, y)
```

An alternative is applying [this patch](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/57-through-option-for-named_scope) to enable a :through option for named_scope:

```
named_scope :a, :conditions => {}
named_scope :b, :conditions => {}
named_scope :ab, :through => [:a, :b]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes [Reusing named_scope to define another named_scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443650/reusing-named-scope-to-define-another-named-scope/3290077#3290077)

I copy it here for your convenience:

You can use proxy_options to recycle one named_scope into another:

```
class Thing
  #...
  named_scope :billable_by, lambda{|user| {:conditions => {:billable_id => user.id } } }
  named_scope :billable_by_tom, lambda{ self.billable_by(User.find_by_name('Tom').id).proxy_options }
  #...
end
```

This way it can be chained with other named_scopes.

I use this in my code and it works perfectly.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Caveat is that proxy_options only returns the scope of the latest named scope, so this cannot be done against another derived named scope

Answer (score 0):

@[PJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011/is-there-a-way-to-combine-named-scopes-into-a-new-named-scope#30719): you know, I had considered that, but dismissed it because I thought I wouldn't be able to later chain on a *third* named scope, like so:

```
Foo.ab(x, y).c(z)
```

But since `ab(x, y)` returns whatever `b(y)` would return, I think the chain would work.  Way to make me rethink the obvious!

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic

Impressive!

To be specific:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  #named_scope :ab, lambda { |a,b| :conditions => { :a => a, :b => b } }
  # alias_scope, returns a Scope defined procedurally
  alias_scope :ab, lambda {
    Foo.a.b
  }
end
```