# Reusing named_scope to define another named_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope, searchlogic

***The problem essence as I see it***

One day, if I'm not mistaken, I have seen an example of reusing a named_scope to define another named_scope. Something like this (can't remember the exact syntax, but that's exactly my question):

```
named_scope :billable, :conditions => ...
named_scope :billable_by_tom, :conditions => {
    :billable => true, 
    :user => User.find_by_name('Tom')
}
```

The question is: what is the exact syntax, if it's possible at all? I can't find it back, and Google was of no help either.

***Some explanations***

Why I actually want it, is that I'm using Searchlogic to define a complex search, which can result in an expression like this:

```
Card.user_group_managers_salary_greater_than(100)
```

But it's too long to be put everywhere. Because, as far as I know, Searchlogic simply defines named_scopes on the fly, I would like to set a named_scope on the Card class like this:

```
named_scope from_big_guys, { user_group_managers_salary_greater_than(100) }
```

- this is where I would use that long Searchlogic method inside my named_scope. But, again, what would be the syntax? Can't figure it out.

***Resume***

So, is named_scope nesting (and I do *not* mean chaining) actually possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011/is-there-a-way-to-combine-named-scopes-into-a-new-named-scope) raised time ago here at SO. 
There is a patch at [lighthouse](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/57-through-option-for-named_scope) to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 8):

You can use **proxy_options** to recycle one named_scope into another:

```
class Thing
  #...
  named_scope :billable_by, lambda{|user| {:conditions => {:billable_id => user.id } } }
  named_scope :billable_by_tom, lambda{ self.billable_by(User.find_by_name('Tom').id).proxy_options }
  #...
end
```

This way it can be chained with other named_scopes.

I use this in my code and it works perfectly.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Caveat is that proxy_options only returns the scope of the latest named scope, so this cannot be done against another derived named scope.

Answer (score 2):

### Rails 3+

I had this same question and the good news is that over the last five years the Rails core team has made some good strides in the scopes department.

In Rails 3+ you can now do this, as you'd expect:

```
scope :billable,        where( due: true )
scope :billable_by_tom, -> { billable.where( user: User.find_by_name('Tom') ) }

Invoice.billable.to_sql         #=> "... WHERE due = 1 ..."
Invoice.billiable_by_tom.to_sql #=> "... WHERE due = 1 AND user_id = 5 ..."
```

*FYI, Rails 3+ they've renamed `named_scope` to just `scope`. I'm also using Ruby 1.9 syntax.*

#### Bonus Round: Generic Scope.

If there are multiple people that are "billable" besides just "Tom" then it might be useful to make a generic scope that accepts a name param that gets passed into the block:

```
scope :billable_by, lambda { |name| billable.where( user: User.find_by_name( name ) ) }
```

Then you can just call it with:

```
Invoice.billable_by( "Tom" ).to_sql #=> "... WHERE due = 1 AND user_id = 5 ..."
```

*Btw, you can see I used the older `lambda` syntax in the bonus round. That's because I think the new syntax looks atrocious when you're passing a param to it: `->( name ) { ... }`.*

Comment: At least since 3.2 there is a clever solution :

   `scope :optional, ->() {where(option: true)}`
   `scope :accepted, ->() {where(accepted: true)}`
    `scope :optional_and_accepted, ->() { self.optional.merge(self.accepted) }`

Comment: @user2481743 Not sure how that's clever (or better). That requires two separate queries and merging the results as opposed to a single query with combined conditionals.

Comment: Well, Absolutely not, `merge` will merge the scope, not the results.
This will result in a single query and a reusable chainable scope.
Have a try, I am sur you'll enjoy this solution !
If the argument of `merge` is an ActiveRecord::Relation it merges the conditions : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge

This result in a single query.

Comment: @user2481743 Oh, that's clever of `ActiveRecord` to do that. So, using your example, couldn't you just go: `scope :optional_and_accepted, ->() { self.optional.accepted }` and not have to use the `merge`?

Comment: Because it is just an example, it could be any other scope defined on any other AR model with a `joins()`.
So I wished to make it explicit.
You are right it could be shortened but it would not serve the teaching purpose.

Comment: @user2481743 Fair enough. Just making sure I wasn't missing something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Chain Scopes.

Why not have a `scope` for stuff just by `Tom` in general, like:

```
scope :by_tom, where( user: User.find_by_name('Tom') )
```

And then you can get those records that are "billable by Tom" with:

```
Record.billable.by_tom
```

Comment: Thinking more on this, you'd really want to put this in a lambda so you could pass in any name there, not just 'Tom', like: `scope :by_tom, ->(name) { where( user: User.find_by_name(name) ) }`

Comment: Typo in my comment above, it should be something like `scope :by, ->(name) { where( user: User.find_by_name(name) ) }` and then you can call it with `Record.by('Tom')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method to combine some named_scope like :

```
def self.from_big_guys
  self.class.user_group_managers_salary_greater_than(100)
end
```

This feature is add on Rails 3 with new syntax (http://m.onkey.org/2010/1/22/active-record-query-interface)

Comment: Defining a class method is inconvenient because it's not a named_scope, so, for example, it can't be chained as such.

Comment: Actually it can be -- just return a scope using where() or whatever: http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html