# Combining two named scopes into an aggregate scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following model with two named scopes:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
 scope :past_two_years, -> {where('end_date > ?', Date.today - 2.years)}
 scope :order_by_end_date, -> {order('end_date DESC')}   
end
```

I now want to define an 'aggregate' scope called `past_two_years_and_order_by_end_date`.  This scope should recycle the existing scopes in order to keep the code DRY.

I know I could create a class method like so:

```
def self.past_two_years_and_order_by_end_date
  past_two_years.order_by_end_date
end
```

but I would prefer to do it with a scope as opposed to a class method.

**Question**:  Is this possible?  Is it possible to write an aggregate scope that combines/recycles existing scopes?

[I did notice this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011/is-there-a-way-to-combine-named-scopes-into-a-new-named-scope), but it is eight years old and rails syntax has since moved on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
scope :past_two_years_and_order_by_end_date, -> {self.past_two_years.order_by_end_date}
```